# Blender Tangent Not working well (Blender 2.78c)

Tags: texturing, uv, normal-map

I am having trouble with my normal maps. I have doing the same baking process since 2.77 but now when I bake my normal maps, the shading ends of looking like this:
[image]

I don't know why it is doing this, I never had this problem until recently. It is UV mapped, sRGB color space, Normal Map is tangent but it's not showing how it is meant to show in the normal map. I know it's nothing to do with texture resolution because I used higher resolutions before and they worked. I would appreciate it if someone can help.

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is - what is it supposed to look like? Difficult to know what the issue is from your description. Please be more specific and explicitly point out the issue.

Comment: The issue is, the tangent shading not lighting up right, the lamp in use is a point lamp but as you see in the screenshot, it is only lighting up in one direction and the normal map is not casting how it is meant to. I don't know how to be specific if it's just meant to be as simple as adding a texture.

In short, the texture is meant to be more bumpy looking instead of flat and the lighting is meant to cast across the whole mesh, not just a specific part.

Comment: I add the normal map, checked the "normal map" section in the image sampling and made sure it's tangent because that's how it was baked, as soon as i turn on the "Normal" in the geometry, it turns out like what you see. How can I show what it meant to look like if I can't get the look? This is why I came here for help, I wouldn't be here otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I thought since you said it worked at 2.77 that you could potentially try it there. Never mind. How about uploading your Normal map and material nodes and/or blend file.

Comment: If it's anything, I think it happened ever since I used the filmic color management addon, I changed it back to standard and it just hasn't worked since. it definitely is something to do with the color spacing and its relations to tangent shading and I don't know how to fix it. I don't know how to upload my blend files here.

Comment: Upload blend files here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. It will generate a link that you can paste into your question.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2982" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2982/)
I dunno if the textures will be there though.

Comment: Afraid the textures aren't there - you need to 'Pack' them into the blend (in the UV/Image Editor, select the image, open the Image menu and select 'Pack Image'. Also, I notice that you're using Blender Render - I'm more familiar with Cycles so someone else might need to help. If you pack the images and re-upload the blend file then use the Edit option on the question to add the link to the question rather than the comments. Hopefully someone will then be able to help.

Comment: Understand, reason I am using blender render is because the textures are for the Blender Game Engine.